# Laravel possible routing issue, getting 404

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel route returning 404 error. I added a new route and action to my controller and a previous route that was working is now not working. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong, but I've been working on this so long I'm probably blind to the actual issue.

Here is my new route

```
Route::get('rental_agreements/{rentalAgreement}/generate_from_quote', 'RentalAgreementController@generateFromQuote');
```

Here are all my POST routes for that controller:

```
Route::post('rental_agreements/quick_link', 'RentalAgreementController@quickLink');
Route::post('rental_agreements/{customer}/store', 'RentalAgreementController@store');
Route::post('rental_agreements/{customer}/generate', 'RentalAgreementController@generate');
Route::post('rental_agreements/{rentalAgreement}/email', 'RentalAgreementController@email');
Route::post('rental_agreements/{rentalAgreement}/store_site_contact', 'RentalAgreementController@storeSiteContact');
```

The new route works fine, the route that is now giving the 404 error is for the store. Previously I did not have /store at the end and it worked fine, but I added this in an attempt to make sure it was not conflicting with something else.

I'm not sure that it's an issue in the routes but I'm not sure where else to look. In my controller, the code runs through the request but gives the 404 as soon as it gets back to the controller. If I remove the request parameter then it works up until saving the resource.

Currently, when I run the code I'm not getting any errors in my log file, which is strange because before I was getting.

> local.ERROR: Class App\Http\Controllers\RentalAgreement does not exist

I have tried clearing the route cache, dumping autoload, and just about everything else I can think of.

Controller - I'm only showing the relevant code.hopefully, I'm not leaving something important out.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Customer;
use App\Location;
use App\RentalAgreement;
use App\Http\Requests\RentalAgreementRequest;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RentalAgreementController extends Controller
{
    public function store(RentalAgreementRequest $rentalAgreementRequest, Customer $customer)
    {
        $rentalAgreement = RentalAgreement::create($rentalAgreementRequest->request->all());

        return redirect()->action('RentalAgreementController@edit', ['customer' => $customer, 'rentalAgreement' => $rentalAgreement])
                               ->with('alert', 'Rental agreement created.');
    }
}
```

Form tag - note $rentalAgreement is not set in this scenario

```
<form method='POST' action="/rental_agreements/{{ isset($rentalAgreement) ? $rentalAgreement->customer->id.'/'.$rentalAgreement->id.'/update' : (isset($customer) ? $customer->id.'/store' : '') }}">
```

Here is the General section from the Chrome Networking tab

> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/rental_agreements/34/store
>
> Request Method: POST
>
> Status Code: 302 Found
>
> Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
>
> Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

I'm not really sure where I;m going wrong. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried rental_agreements/{rentalAgreement}/site_contact instead of rental_agreements/{rentalAgreement}/store_site_contact? 'Cause I suspect that Laravel is being confused

Comment: Please check your Controller name and class name are same or not?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I think the name of the controller and model are good because all the other routes work, it's just the store route that does not. I did confirm they are both spelled the same and the class names inside match the file names.

Comment: Pedro I actually tried removing all other RentalAgreement routes before just to see if there was a conflict and I still get the 404.